# Me da resultado 0 y no se cual es la solución

Tags: c++

Estuve intentando un tiempo, necesito que me diga la edad que voy a tener en 2050, el problema es que cuando me abre el programa y le pongo los números me da como resultado 0.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int calcularAnyos(int anhio, int edad);
int main(){
    int anhio; int edad;
    int edadMayor;
    cout<<"Digite anio y edad actual: "<<endl;
    cin>>anhio;
    cin>>edad;
    edadMayor = calcularAnyos(anhio,edad);
    cout<<"La edad que vas a tener en 2050 es: "<<edadMayor<<endl;
    return 0;
}
int calcularAnyos(int anhio, int edad)
{
    int mayor;
    {
        2050 - anhio + edad == mayor;
    }
    return mayor;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 6):

> el problema es que cuando me abre el programa y le pongo los números me da como resultado 0

Es curioso, porque debería darte un valor indeterminado pero diferente a cero. Cualquier programador experimentado al leer tu función `calcularAnyos` tendría un esguince de dendritas y un trombo generalizado.

Para empezar, devuelves una variable en la que no asignas ningún valor:

```
int mayor; // Valor indeterminado
{
    2050 - anhio + edad == mayor;
}
return mayor; // Devuelve sin asignar valor
```

Para acabar, haces una operación que no se guarda en ningún sitio:

```
/*                       _____ Operación booleana
                        /
         ______________^___________
        /                          \        */
        2050 - anhio + edad == mayor;
/*      \________ ________/
                 v
                 \____ Operación aritmética */
```

El resultado de comparar una operación aritmética con un número da lugar a una operación booleana que, para colmo, no guardas en ningún sitio.

Posiblemente, lo que querías hacer es lo siguiente:

```
int edad_el_anhio(int anhio, int anhio_actual, int edad)
{
    return edad + (anhio - anhio_actual);
}
```

Sumar a la edad, la diferencia entre el año actual y el año de destino.

Comment: La del esguince de dendritas me la apunto xDD

Comment: Gracias paula por tanto...

Answer (score 2):

No sé qué intentaste hacer en esta línea de tu código
`2050 - anhio + edad == mayor;`
pero estas condicionando a que la **edad** tenga el mismo valor que tenga **mayor** que declaraste como un entero y no lo inicializaste, si cambias tu función **calcularAnyos**

```
int calcularAnyos(int anhio, int edad)
{

    int mayor=0;
{
mayor = 2050 - anhio + edad;
}
    return mayor;
}
```

funcionará y te dará el resultado de las edades que coloques

Answer (score 1):

No estás generando bien la asignación en tu función. Sería de este modo:

```
int calcularAnyos(int anhio, int edad)
{
    int mayor;

    mayor = 2050 - anhio + edad;

    return mayor;
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Una función de tres líneas que podría ser una: `return 2050 - anhio + edad;`

Comment: Lo sé. Simplemente quería dejarlo tal y como él lo había puesto.